# Code for calculating weights of Uniform substrings

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++14

In the following code we have to first calculate the weights of uniform substrings present in our strings . Uniform sub strings are those which contain just one character like "a" or "aaa".
The weight of the character is defined as 
a-1
b-2......z-26.

After calculating the weights of all the valid uniform substrings we will be given with various queries and we have to check whether the given no. is the array or not.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string s;
  cin>>s;
  int i=0,j=0,k=0;
  int arr[10000];
  int c=0;  
  while(s[i]!='\0')
  {
    int x=(int)s[i];
    x=x-96;
    arr[c++]=x;
    j=i+1;
    int sum=x;
    while(s[j]==s[i])
    {
      sum+=x;
      arr[c++]=sum;
      j++;
    }
    i=j;
  }
  int q;
  cin>>q;
  for(i=0;i<q;i++)
  {
    int val;
    cin>>val;
    bool exists=find(begin(arr),end(arr),val)!=end(arr);
    if(exists==true)
      cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
    else
      cout<<"No"<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
abccddde
6
1
3
12
5
9
10
```

Expected output:

```
YES
YES
YES
YES
NO
NO
```

Actual outcome:

```
YES
YES
YES
YES
NO
YES
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Bart, I think he wants us to help him find problem in his code.

Comment: @kiner_shah , i got your solution but can you please tell me what was the error in my code.

Comment: @Aryan, the problem is probably in the section where you fill `arr[]`. BTW, `s[i] != '\0'` is for C-style character arrays, I am not sure whether it works for `std::string`. I think the problem is with the `while` loops, please check if they are properly implemented. Check with the case in which you got wrong ans.

Comment: @kiner_shah , ya i have already checked that part of my code and it works completely fine and the values of the substrings that i am storing in the array is also correct but i don't know why i am getting wrong output for the query 10

Comment: @Aryan, do a dry run for query 10 and see if your code is behaving properly. Sometimes edge test cases can be missed, so code works for most of the test cases and fails on edge test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in a simpler and easy to understand way. I used `std::set` to store unique possible values and then used its `find()` method to check if query value is present in the set.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;

    set<int> possible_val;

    int c = 1;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s[i] == s[i - 1]) {
            c++;
        }
        else {          // If current char different from previous char
            // If substring is ccc, then put 3, 6 and 9 in the set
            for (int j = 1; j <= c; j++)
                possible_val.insert(j * (s[i - 1] - 'a' + 1));
            // Reset counter to 1
            c = 1;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= c; j++)
        possible_val.insert(j * (s[s.length() - 1] - 'a' + 1));

    int q, x;
    cin >> q;
    while (q-- > 0) {
        cin >> x;
        if (possible_val.find(x) != possible_val.end()) cout << "YES\n";
        else cout << "NO\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The link where I tested the problem (passes given input): https://ideone.com/OHfxCq